# What should be the expected behavior of Consumer when Kafka Broker or Zookeeper goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a local test setup for Kafka and Zookeeper.

Here are the details.

OS: Windows

Kafka: 2.0.1 (*Single Node Single Broker*)
According to these Stackoverflow threads, Consumers should go down if the zookeeper or broker goes down.

[What happens if Zookeeper fails completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808583/what-happens-if-zookeeper-fails-completely)

[Kafka cluster zookeeper failure handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346938/kafka-cluster-zookeeper-failure-handling)

Even if the Zookeeper is down, Producer(Conduktor) and Consumer(Node js) are Working fine. The consumer is still registered.

What should be the expected behavior of consumers?

Comment: This answer might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499738/9657108

Comment: @arunkvelu , according to this Answer Producer and Consumer both will work fine in case of Zookeeper failure. But Should we rely on this behavior or the behavior of Clients will be unpredictable? As per my latest testing (1 out of 4 times Cousmer was not responding after zookeeper was down for 1 hr ) and other forums, this Behaviour is not consistent.